# Bash-completion and grep

Tags: bash, grep, autocomplete

I installed a program (`iftop`) on Debian Squeeze but some days ago I forgot it's name.
I had only this information about the program:

1) It was called `*top`

2) I could find it using `bash-completions`.

I wanted to `grep` all the options of `bash-completion`.
Do you have any idea on how can I do it?

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but an alternative solution: 1) locate top (long list of all installed files with `top` in their filename).  2) find /path/to/search -name "*top" -print. (same, but searches the disk while locate uses a database).

Comment: `locate` is a very bad choice. It might not necessarily be up to date and it matches *all* files, not only executables. The `find` solution is better, but you need to add something like `-perm /+x` to match only executables.

Comment: @Hennes: It would be nice with longer words, but with "*top" it prints too much possibilities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `compgen` builtin to get a list of possible completions:

```
compgen -c | grep top
```

You can request completions for various types of completion actions like commands, aliases, functions..., e.g. `-c` is equivalent to `-A commands`. See `man bash` for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Using `compgen` is definitely a nice one. Alternatively, and that would work with any POSIX shell, you could check the commands in `$PATH` with:

```
(IFS=:; set -f; ls -- $PATH | grep top$)
```

With `zsh`:

```
type -m '*top'
```

You can also query the whatis database:

```
man -ks1:8 top$
```

Answer (score 2):

While you can [figure it out from the completion system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69093/bash-completion-grep/69096#69096), this isn't the most obvious method.

Almost all programs installed by pacakges are in `/usr/bin`, so you can list the programs in `/usr/bin` whose name ends with `top`:

```
echo /usr/bin/*top
```

You can list the files by inode change time. The modification time of an installed program is usually the time it was compiled, because archiving and installation tools copy the modification time alongside the data. But the inode change time of a file is the last time anything happened to it, including being extracted or copied (in fact, it's having its modification time changed that resets the inode change time). Since you installed the program recently, it's one of the last ones shown by the following command:

```
ls -lctr /usr/bin/*top
```

Remove the `r` option if you want to start looking from the top rather than from the bottom.

You could also look at the log of programs you installed. They're in `/var/log/history.log`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a shell function which searches your PATH and known directories that contain binaries, but that are not in your PATH. Example:

```
findprogram() {
  ls $(echo $PATH:/sbin:/usr/sbin | sed "s/:/\ /g") | grep "$1" | sort --unique
}
```

Usage:

```
findprogram top
```

This outputs a sorted list of candidates.